# From Coordinate to Degree

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, coordinates

How could I get the angle in Degree from 0 to 360 from Cartesian coordinate such that :

```
{1,0}  = 0   Degree
{0,1}  = 90  Degrees
{-1,0} = 180 Degrees
{0,-1} = 270 Degrees
```

I am having a hard Time with ArcTan to get the angle bet 180 to 359...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
f[x_List] := Mod[ArcTan @@ x /Pi 180 Degree, 360 Degree]

f /@ {{0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}
(*
 -> {270 \[Degree], 90 \[Degree], 0, 180 \[Degree]}
*)
```

**Edit**

As the previous form was criticized upon, here is another way to do the same. Not so easy to follow for my taste:

```
f = (180 /Pi ArcTan @@ #)~Mod~360 &
```

Comment: Why do you use `f[#]&` instead of `f`?

Comment: @Sza As usual, I was trying several alternatives and forgot to clean up the code :)

Comment: Why do you use `ArcTan[Sequence @@ x]` instead of `ArcTan @@ x`?

Comment: @Sjoerd Because I think it is easier to follow for the OP

Comment: I'd say you're making it more complicated. How on earth can the first form seen as simpler than the second?

Comment: @Sjoerd because I saw previously that many newcomers don't realize that `@@` removes `List[]`. But it may be a prejudice.

Comment: I feel that `Sequence`+`Apply` is much more exotic than `Apply` on its own. `Sequence` is a function learners of MMA will encounter rather late if ever.

Comment: @acl Yoda posted the same comment and then deleted it. The upvote from Mr. was the only reason to do the archeological job of searching for the `~` at my non conventional keyboard :D

Comment: @acl Still worse `f = (ArcTan @@ #/Pi)~Mod~2 180 &`

Comment: @belisarius ouch. on the other hand, the previous construction had 5 symbols one after the other, namely, `@@#)~`, while this has only `@@ #/`, a mere 4...

Comment: @belisarius yes i felt a definite sense of relief when I saw in the comments that i'm not the only one overwhelmed by Mr.W's notational heroics

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CoordinateToDegree[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := 
 Rescale[ArcTan[-x, y], {-Pi, Pi}, {360, 0}]
```

Using `ArcTan[-x,y]` you will be aligning on the branch cut so you get a continuous function for the angle. Then `Rescale` maps the range `-Pi...Pi` to `0...360`.

Here is simple `Manipulate` which demonstrates this solution:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
  Orange, Disk[],
  Black, Text[Style[CoordinateToDegree[Cos[t], Sin[t]], "Title"], {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]},
 PlotRange -> 1.4], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this works, despite being ugly:

```
todeg[x_, y_] := If[# < 0, 360 + #, #] &@(N@ArcTan[x, y]/Degree)
```